# complex time difference operation using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Below is a small sample of a very large dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

In [32]: df3
Out[32]:
       Location_ID                Time
0       10000000568366 2012-05-31 14:08:00
1       10000000257225 2012-05-31 07:22:00
2       10000000730693 2012-05-31 02:19:00
3       10000000257225 2012-05-30 12:20:00
4       10000001072890 2012-05-30 11:19:00
5       10000000811587 2012-05-31 03:09:00
6       10000000094837 2012-06-02 08:39:00
7       10000000730693 2012-06-01 14:04:00
8       10000000955747 2012-05-31 07:24:00
9       10000000924241 2012-05-30 14:48:00
10      10000000893286 2012-05-18 13:12:00
11      10000000924241 2012-05-31 01:56:00
12      10000000211696 2012-05-30 02:09:00
13      10000000211696  2012-05-29 11:41:00
14      10000000084450 2012-05-31 18:34:00
15      10000000939505 2012-06-02 18:12:00
16      10000000893286  2012-05-31 22:54:00
17      10000000811598 2012-06-01 07:55:00
18      10000000683255 2012-05-29 03:44:00
```

I am trying to find the time difference in seconds between consecutive rows of "Time" for a particular  Location_ID. I am using pandas.to_numeric which converts it into nanoseconds , then divide it by 1000000000 to get the result in seconds:

```
  df4 = df3.assign(time_difference=df3['Time'].groupby('Location_ID').apply(lambda x : (pd.to_numeric(x.shift()-x).abs())/1000000000))
```

The error I get is:

```
KeyError: 'Location_ID'
```

Comment: this works `df3.assign(time_difference=df3['Time']).groupby('Location_ID').first().apply(lambda x : (pd.to_numeric(x.shift()-x).abs())/1000000000)`.

Comment: getting a syntax error
 df3.assign(time_difference=df3['Time']).groupby('Location_ID‌​').first().apply(lam‌​bda x: (pd.to_numeric(x.shift()-x).abs())/1000000000)
                                     ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: align the statement correctly it works.

Comment: @shivsn.. what do you mean by aligning the statement?can you paste the aligned statement here?